# looking for the first n that satisfies this equation

Tags: inequality

I have been trying to find the first $ n \in \Bbb N $ that will satisfy the following equation:

$$ \sqrt[n]{2} - 1 < 10^{-8} $$

So far I have tried something like

$$ \sqrt[n]{2} - 1 < 10^{-8} \Leftrightarrow $$

$$ 2^{1/n} < 10^{-8} + 1 \Leftrightarrow $$

$$ 2 < (10^{-8} + 1)^n \Leftrightarrow $$

I am not sure how to continue and go about solving this one. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: Try using logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so we have,

> $$(1+10^{-8})^n\gt 2$$

We use the following trivial fact:

> $$\forall~a,b~\in\Bbb{R^+}~,~a\leq b\implies \ln a\leq \ln b$$

We get,

$$n\ln(1+10^{-8})\gt \ln 2\implies n\gt \frac{\ln2}{\ln(1+10^{-8})}\approx \frac{\ln2}{10^{-8}}\approx 0.693\times 10^8$$

Comment: We also use the fact that $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ for $x$ very close to $0$. As you can see, $n$ is surely gonna be a large number and all we can do is get a nice _approximation_.

Comment: "all we can do is get a nice approximation."  False.  I can give you an exact value for the minimum n that satisfies this inequality.  the answer is n = 69314719.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost, I meant _without calculator_, of course. With a calculator, anyone can get that.

Comment: And how did you compute $\frac{ln(2)}{10^{-8}}$?  Did you use any nice approximations to get that? (perhaps you simply know that ln(2) is approximately .693)  or did you, say, use a calculator?  so why use approximations on one step, and then use a calculator for the next?  If its possible to get an exact answer, then that answer should be given exactly.  Since the problem asks for the first $n$ that satisfies the inequality, that is what should be given as an answer, not an approximation.

Comment: @PaddlingGhost, actually yes. The value of $\ln2$ is used by me frequently and so I know that it is approximately $0.693$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the logarithm to get $n$ out of the exponent.

Comment: One-liners rarely make good answers.  I don't doubt that taking a logarithm can help, but such a suggestion deserves a more concrete form.  Which expression should the OP take the logarithm of?

Comment: I took it he asked for a suggestion to continue, not a solution.

Comment: This is a good suggestion

Comment: It would be an improvement to add a note justifying the OP's if-and-only-if logic.  Since we are following a chain of inequalities, one needs that logarithm is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binomial expansion of
(1 + x)^n = 1+ nx +.....
(when x is much smaller than 1, which is clearly true here). 
So, we get
1 + n*(10^-8)>2
Or, n > 10^8